# I called a function from two pages .One page works and other page does not works properly

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

Include tree page (List, View, Edit) in index and used same command tow page (List and View) .When I List.xhtml  page ‘s View or Edit button click and open it; but View.xhtml page’s Edit button click then  show in flowing massage:

```
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action '#{instituteController.viewEdit}' with outcome 'null'
```

.

I want View page’s Edit button click to edit page open into index page.
List.xhtml code:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{instituteController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListInstituteViewLink}">
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton action="#{instituteController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListInstituteEditLink}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

View.xhtml code

```
 <h:commandButton action="#{instituteController.viewEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListInstituteEditLink}">
 <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

instituteController.java code:

```
   public String prepareEdit() {
    current = (Institute) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "index";
}
 public String viewEdit() {

          return "null";
}
```

If I return "index" ; this command don't work. Again show this code:

```
          public String viewEdit() {

          return "index";
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
public String viewEdit() {
    // ...
    return "null";
}
```

You're returning a `String` instance with value of `"null"`. This is not the same as the literal  `null`.

Fix it accordingly:

```
public String viewEdit() {
    // ...
    return null;
}
```

or just return nothing:

```
public void viewEdit() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But this page show when I refresh or reload page. I want show this page without reload or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning "null", is written in your exception. Return empty string if you want to stay on the same page or name of the page where do you want to go.